# Set style for only the first element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have set all the styles of section to be locked using :

```
$("section").attr("class", "XXX Locked");
```

but i want the first section in the page to have a different style 
like :

```
$("section").first().attr("class", "XXX");
```

but this doesn't work...

this first element is generated dynamically so `document.getbyId(smtgn).value` won't work

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: If you create a JSFiddle that might help...!

Comment: @James Donnelly Doesn't work = means that the class value stays "XXX Locked" instead of "XXX"

Comment: _this first element is generated dynamically so document.getbyId(smtgn).value won't work_? Since when wouldn't that work?

Comment: Not enough information. Could be anything.

Comment: @Greed, you're executing the second line after the first one, right?

Comment: Don't answer your own question in the question, especially when their is a valid answer below. You should mark that as the answer.

Comment: @Liam somebody should have thougt about that when they put a validation that correct answer can't be sELEcTeD for the first 10 min

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addClass and http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass and http://api.jquery.com/removeClass should be used here.

Comment: @Blazemonger what are you doing man, the correct answer has been selected?

Comment: @Greeed yes, I can see that. But you're still using a brick when you ought to use a hammer. `.attr()` is (usually) the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use the :first selector..

```
$("section:first").attr("class", "XXX");
```

Comment: Can you explain how and why this would solve the problem?

Comment: This has solved the problem, thanks alot

Comment: "Set style for only the first element using JQuery"  +  $("section").first().attr("class", "XXX");  

Anyone could see that THIS is EXACTLY what he was looking for. -.- omg.

Comment: Chaining into `first()` is exactly equivalent to applying the `:first` selector. Your suggestion cannot solve the questioner's problem as it is stated. I suspect something else is going on.

Comment: I don't get how this solved it. It seems identical to what the OP is doing.

Comment: clearly isnt lads. @Greeed Accept the answer that solved it.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-vs-first-selector

Comment: @JFit, this is about behavior, not performance.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi It can and it had.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: This should have been exactly the same as the original, as you stated. Did you notice the perf actually shows this answer is much slower than the original question? `.first()` rules. :)

Comment: andddddd do you see? or... are u just saying that ignorantly. :D